# FRAUD from same person

Tags: fraud

We have been defrauded many times by the same person, under different names and billing addresses. However, he consistently uses the same shipping address. **How can we block some address or postal codes so we don’t get defrauded again?**

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try this [fraud prevention module](https://marketplace.magento.com/hexasoft-module-fraudlabspro.html) as it is free, easy to set up and provides validation rules customization to block addresses or postal codes for your case to prevent fraud orders.

Answer (score 0):

There are many fraud paid services, for example [signifyd](https://www.signifyd.com/magento/) in a [module](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/sales/fraud-protection-signifyd.html) part of default installation.  There are other services like [riskified](https://www.riskified.com/) or those found [on the magento marketplace](https://marketplace.magento.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=fraud&ext_platform=Magento%202).

Most of these have ongoing costs (must be indicated as per magento marketplace terms and conditions in the description)... but there is at least this one [Fraud Prevention M2 by Plugin Company](https://marketplace.magento.com/plugincompany-fraudprevention.html) that *"does not involve any additional service costs or periodical subscription fees"*) I think is closest to your needs.